# Нужна ли запятая в "причём что"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в "...ПРИЧЁМ ЧТО растущие абсолютно хаотично..."?

---

**Дополнение**

Вот всё предложение:

*Это было похоже на густо переплетённую виноградную лозу(...), причем что растущую абсолютно хаотично, то ли продольным то ли поперечным узором(...), хаотичным, и в тоже время затейливым и замысловатым.*

Не судите строго, я не особо грамотен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Олег, мало того, что фрагмент без начала и конца, так ещё слово "причём" тут совершенно не у дел. Должно быть "притом".

Вот по идее запятая "задумана" ***перед*** присоединительной конструкцией, начинающейся с *причём/притом*.

Запятая перед "что" не нужна.

---

После дополнения к вопросу.

> Это было похоже на густо переплетённую виноградную лозу...., причем
>   что растущую абсолютно хаотично, то ли продольным то ли поперечным
>   узором..., хаотичным, и в тоже время затейливым и замысловатым.

Сейчас исправим, делов-то.

Уберём лишнее, нарисуем нужное.

*Это было похоже на густо переплетённую виноградную лозу, причём
растущую абсолютно хаотично, то ли с продольным, то ли с поперечным
узором - неупорядоченным, сумбурным и в то же время затейливым и замысловатым.*

(Чтобы не было тавтологии с *хаосом,* пришлось предложить синонимы, сворованные у Инета.)

Comment: Спасибо большое Галина")

Comment: Олежек! Тут вместо спасиба ставят оценку (клик по верхнему треугольничку слева от ответа) и, если ответ дан исчерпывающий, кликают по галочке - внизу слева же. )))

Comment: "Лозу с узором" или "растущую узором"? Мне кажется, здесь уместно второе.

Comment: Галина ещё раз огромное спасибо..")

Comment: Очень помогли ")